# rails on ruby/jruby performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, jruby

I have watched a video that introduce to Jruby and the guy there make a test creating threads and executing the same program on Jruby and Ruby. It was a lot faster on Jruby since on Ruby there are no real threads:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/376-jruby-basics

Could anyone say if this mean that when I am using rails on Jruby my app will be more faster too and will be this a common scenario or just when I am using threads?

Also, as there are same gems for Jruby and ruby, is there any huge difference between them - I mean if in Jruby you can use threads it will be more practical to rewrite the whole gem using them?

Comment: Different implementations are faster/slower doing different things. You will only know if you benchmark YOUR code.

Comment: I am not asking for particular case - I am asking for the a whole project performance. A particular test is made in the link in the question body and such specific case do not means that I should always use Jruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Could anyone say if this mean that when I am using rails on Jruby 
my app will be more faster too and will be this a common scenario or just when I am using threads?`

Yes, your app will be more faster in any scenario and even more now with Java 7 it brings a lot of performance updates. If you’re using JRuby and moving from Java 6 to Java 7 you should see a performance improvement. Remember that your JRuby runs on th JVM.

`Also, as there are same gems for Jruby and ruby, is there any huge difference between them - I mean if in Jruby you can use threads it will be more practical to rewrite the whole gem using them?`

About gems and how they build them I'm not so sure but I think that not everything should be developed using theads even when you could, but thats my opinion.

Comment: I think that's oversimplifying slightly. I've got code that runs faster with jruby and code that doesn't (using jruby 1.7 on java 7).

Comment: @Frederick Cheung, maybe this is just a specific case? I am asking this because I am reading rails now, and I want to know if it deserves to do the tutorials and tasks using jRuby instead.

Comment: I think you could choose JRuby for many other reasons as well, but at the end it's up to you, I recommend you JRuby because of my experience but I also invite you to try both and see what fits better to your needs. Maybe in some cases as @Frederick say Ruby could run faster but as I say Jruby has some other things to offer.

Comment: @M.Octavio thanks you. I have read about the other advantages as more libraries on java and Unicode support.

Answer (score 0):

It's all depends on you project requirement but JRUBY slower than Ruby unless you can convert all you code in BYTE code but some scenario like Threading JRUBY have more advantages and most common disadvantage is JRUBY have lesser support than RUBY.